# Rspec model test with Fabricator & let(...) format. Console shows no data in databse but there is.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, pry, fabrication-gem

I don't understand why it returns empty when I type "Video.all" first time in console after it did not pass the test, but if I specify them like "video" & "video2", and then I type "Video.all" it correctly returns the 2 videos. Does anyone know why this does not work?

app/models/video.rb

```
def self.search_by_title(search_term)
 if search_term
  find(:all, conditions: ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%"])
 else
  find(:all)
 end
end
```

My model testing:

spec/models/video_spec.rb

```
  describe "#search_by_title" do
    let(:video) { Fabricate(:video, title: 'Family Guy', description: 'description1')}
    let(:video2) { Fabricate(:video, title: 'Futurama', description: 'description2')}

    it "should return all the videos if the keyword is found in video titles" do
      expect(Video.search_by_title("F")).to include(video2, video)
    end

    it "should return empty array when nothing is found" do
      expect(Video.search_by_title("Test Title")).to eq []
    end

    it "should return the video if the search keyword matches exactly" do
      expect(Video.search_by_title("Family Guy")).to include video
    end

    it "should return all the videos if the keyword is empty" do
      binding.pry
      expect(Video.search_by_title("")).to include(video2, video)
    end
```

Result of pry

```
@ line 33 :

    28:     it "should return the video if the search keyword matches exactly" do
    29:       expect(Video.search_by_title("Family Guy")).to include video
    30:     end
    31: 
    32:     it "should return all the videos if the keyword is empty" do
 => 33:       binding.pry
    34:       expect(Video.search_by_title("")).to include(video2, video)
    35:     end  
    36:   end
    37: 
    38:   describe "#average_ratings" do

[1] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1>)> Video.all
=> []
[2] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1>)> video
=> #<Video id: 1, title: "Family Guy", small_cover_url: nil, large_cover_url: nil, description: "description1", created_at: "2013-05-15 21:35:52", updated_at: "2013-05-15 21:35:52">
[3] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1>)> video2
=> #<Video id: 2, title: "Futurama", small_cover_url: nil, large_cover_url: nil, description: "description2", created_at: "2013-05-15 21:35:55", updated_at: "2013-05-15 21:35:55">
[4] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1>)> Video.all
=> [#<Video id: 1, title: "Family Guy", small_cover_url: nil, large_cover_url: nil, description: "description1", created_at: "2013-05-15 21:35:52", updated_at: "2013-05-15 21:35:52">,
 #<Video id: 2, title: "Futurama", small_cover_url: nil, large_cover_url: nil, description: "description2", created_at: "2013-05-15 21:35:55", updated_at: "2013-05-15 21:35:55">]
[5] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1>)>
```

Comment: solved. just add ! after let.   like let!(...)

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your code even though you "solved" it.

It is the `search_by_title` method.

Try the following in your console:

```
> def test(arg)
>   if arg
>     puts "there is arg"
>   else
>     puts "there is no arg"
>   end
> end
> a = ""
> test(a)
> #=> "there is arg"
```

See, your `else` will never be fired because empty string is arg.

You need to refactor it like this

```
 if search_term.blank?
   find(:all)
 else
   find(:all, conditions: ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%"])
 end
```